# $\mathbb P(X_1 < X_2)$, given that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are both exponentially distributed.

Tags: probability, exponential-distribution

In a tutorial exercise I am asked to determine:

> $\mathbb P(X_1 < X_2)$, given that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are both independently exponentially distributed with the same parameter $\lambda$.

I would be inclined to just write $\mathbb P(X_1-X_2 <0) = \mathbb P(Y<0)$, where $Y=X_1-X_2$, but would this not simply be $0$?

What would change if they would each come with their own parameters $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$?

What I know:
$$\mathbb P(X_1 \geq x)= \lambda e^{-\lambda x}.$$
The hint in the books says to condition on the value of $X_2$, I'm not completely following what is meant.

Comment: Hint: For the sake of intuition, think about discrete random variables first. You would approach it as $P[X_1 < X_2] = P[X_1 < X_2 | X_2 = x_2]*P[X_2 = x_2]$, and sum over all possible values of $x_2$.

Comment: So you would turn it into an integration over all such values in the continuous case.

Comment: Yep, replace the discrete probabilities with the respective continuous pmf, and the sum over all possible values of $x_2$ turns into an integral wrt $x_2$.

Comment: $P [X_1 < X_2]= \int_{t=0}^\infty P[X_1 <X_2 | X_2 =t] P[X_2=t] dt$?

Comment: Which then becomes $\int_{t=0}^\infty P[X_1 <t] P[X_2=t] dt$?

Comment: I'm not sure how to proceed.
$$ \int_{t=0}^\infty \lambda_1e^{-\lambda_1 t} P[X_2=t]dt  \dots$$

Comment: You're almost there, just need to plug in the distributions of $X_1$ and $X_2$ and integrate. You'll use a CDF for $X_1$ and a PDF for $X_2$.

Comment: Oh yes because cumulative means all the values beyond some value summed up while a PDf is at a particular point.

Comment: $$P[X_1<X_2]=\int_{t=0}^\infty (1-e^{-\lambda_1 t})\lambda_2e^{-\lambda_2 t} ~?$$

Comment: This gets me $\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1 + \lambda_2}$ as other sources also seem to indicate, yay! :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124268/discussion-between-amaan-m-and-algebra-geek).

Comment: $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X_1\,{<}\,X_2) &=\iint_{0\leqslant s\lt t\lt \infty} f_{\small X_1,X_2}(s,t)\,\mathrm d \langle s,t\rangle\\[1ex] &= \int_0^\infty\int_s^\infty f_{\small X_1}(s)\,f_{\small X_2}(t)\,\mathrm d t\,\mathrm d s\\[1ex]&=\int_0^\infty \lambda_1\,\mathrm e^{-\lambda_1 s} \int_s^\infty \lambda_2\,\mathrm e^{-\lambda_2 t}\,\mathrm dt\,\mathrm ds&&=\int_0^\infty f_{\small X_1}(s)\,\mathsf P(X_2\,{>}\, s)\,\mathrm d s\\[1ex]&=\int_0^\infty \lambda_1\mathrm e^{-(\lambda_1+\lambda_2) s}\,\mathrm d s\\[1ex]&=\dfrac {\lambda_1}{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When they have the same distribution, $P(X_1\lt X_2)=P(X_2\lt X_1)=\frac{1}{2}$.  Because the distributions are continuous, $P(X_1=X_2)=0$

Comment: I also figured if we solve the general case, this would follow from the simple case since $\frac{\lambda}{\ámbda + \lambda} = \frac{1}{2}.$ But I've been looking at other posts trying to understand what is happening.

Comment: For the general case, use convolution to get the distribution of the sum $X_1+(-X_2)$.